# Setting a different ancestor for WPF UserControl in VS2008

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I would like to create a WPF user control that inherits from a different ancestor than UserControl class.

The problem is that visual studio keeps overriding my setting and change it back to UserControl resulting in an error: 
Partial declarations of 'XXX' must not specify different base classes

every time I re-build the project the auto generated file xxx.g.cs is being regenerated with UserControl as the parnet...

I'm using VS2008 and C#

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a `CustomControl` instead of a `UserControl`. A brief list of the differences can be found [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html).

If you want to create your own UI you can either overwrite the Template property of the control with a global style or a quick Google search should give you some tutorials about how to create CustomControls with their own default UI.

Comment: I do need a UserControl. (and I used this practice all the time in WinForm without a problem)

Answer (score 0):

In the XAML file of your control, have you changed the document tag from `UserControl` to something else?

Comment: The root tag of your XAML document.